# How can I only read changed docs from Firestore database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is primarily a read-cost concern. My app only needs to retrieve data from `Firestore` on app launch, so I'm not sure if using a listener is the best way to get changed docs. My database is a list of meals, it should be around 50 meals (docs). How can I check if there any changes to the docs on app launch while minimizing reads (realistically there should be no reads if no changes are made to the database)

This is my code currently:

```
  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot =
      await firestoreInstance.collection('meals').get();
  
  List<Map> collectionData = [];
  for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
    collectionData.add(doc.data() as Map);
  }

  return collectionData;
```

it's called on the main method before runApp()

Comment: Firestore doesn't remember the last update time of a document, and it doesn't know when you last queried the collection.  You will need to record these things and use them on your own.  The duplicate has details.